# Wordpress - adding custom field to category page

Tags: wordpress

I am want to add a custom `select` field to the category page of wordpress.
I tried searching google and WordPress but solution I found were outdated and not support ajax update.

Kindly show me an example which adds a custom field to category page and uses ajax.
Thanks

**Update:**

below link solved my problem. simple and awesome

http://en.bainternet.info/2011/wordpress-category-extra-fields

Comment: i guess you have answer of this question. could you please share the answer of this question please? i want to add custom field to category page.

Comment: You can read the tutorial here http://en.bainternet.info/2011/wordpress-category-extra-fields, I am using this

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of solutions but all of them have one thing in common. They are saving that extra field value added to a category in the option table not in the post meta table. Because on the next wp update one may loose the custom category field values. so if your problem get solved by this then hare are the links to do the same.

[A whole discussion related to your problem.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8736/add-custom-field-to-category)

[A tutorial based on you posted question.](http://en.bainternet.info/2011/wordpress-category-extra-fields)